# ¿Como llenar un ListView personalizado dimanicamente en android?

Tags: java, android, listview

estoy intentando llenar una lista en Android de forma dinamica con un FOR

El ListView lo se llenar de forma manual asi:

```
 Lista_productos_categoria lista_productos_categoria_data[] = new Lista_productos_categoria[]{

            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto1", "$50.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto2", "$40.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto3", "$34.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto4", "$44.300"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto5", "$99.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto6", "$140.400"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto7", "$90.040")
    };

    Lista_productos_categorias_Adapter adapter = new Lista_productos_categorias_Adapter(this, R.layout.item_lista_productos_categoria, lista_productos_categoria_data);

    lista_productos= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_productos);


    lista_productos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Lo que quiero es si por ejemplo necesito 100 productos, no tener que codificar uno por uno;

habia pensado algo asi pero no me funciono:

```
Lista_productos_categoria lista_productos_categoria_data[] = new Lista_productos_categoria[]{

            for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
                new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto1", "$50.000");
            }


    };
```

de cualquier manera dejo todo el codigo del activity, gracias de antemano

```
public class categoria_productos extends Activity {
String categoria;
TextView cat_actual;
String name_pr, pre_pr;
ListView lista_productos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_productos_categoria);

    cat_actual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoria_actual);

    Lista_productos_categoria lista_productos_categoria_data[] = new Lista_productos_categoria[]{

            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto1", "$50.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto2", "$40.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto3", "$34.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto4", "$44.300"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto5", "$99.000"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground, "producto6", "$140.400"),
            new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto7", "$90.040")
    };

    Lista_productos_categorias_Adapter adapter = new Lista_productos_categorias_Adapter(this, R.layout.item_lista_productos_categoria, lista_productos_categoria_data);

    lista_productos= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_productos);


    lista_productos.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista_productos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            TextView producto_Sel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_producto);
            TextView producto_Sel_pre= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pre_producto);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"INGRESANDO AL PRODUCTO " + producto_Sel.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //voy a intentar ingresar a solo producto
            name_pr= producto_Sel.getText().toString();
            pre_pr=producto_Sel_pre.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(categoria_productos.this, Solo_Producto.class );
            intent.putExtra("precio", pre_pr);
            intent.putExtra("nombre", name_pr);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null){
        categoria = extras.getString("valor");
        cat_actual.setText(categoria);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: En el siguiente link resuelven tu duda, haciendo uso de un for como tu planteas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184323/how-to-add-values-in-listview-with-the-help-of-a-loop-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

> la variable NUMERO_ELEMENTOS contiene la cantidad de elementos del listado que se generará
>   dinámicamente:

```
Lista_productos_categoria lista_productos_categoria_data[] = new Lista_productos_categoria[NUMERO_ELEMENTOS];

            for (int i=0;i<NUMERO_ELEMENTOS;i++){
                lista_productos_categoria_data[i] = new Lista_productos_categoria(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "producto1", "$50.000");
            }
```